# Error when running react native uber clone

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native, github

I am a complete beginner trying to open a react native uber clone application on visual studio (windows). https://github.com/coderkhalide/uber-clone

Here are the steps and errors that occurred, any help would be greatly appreciated. I am sure I'm making some noob mistake.

NPM version 8.19.2

1. copied the github repository into VS
2. deleted yarn.lock file
3. in terminal - npm install and I immediately receive errors:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
npm ERR!   react-native-safe-area-context@"4.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-elements
npm ERR!   react-native-elements@"^3.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\anon\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.    

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\anon\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-09T23_44_43_850Z-debug-0.log
```

4. So then, I type in npm install --uber-clone --legacy-peer-deps
   and it loads for a while, then I receive the following errors:

```
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@1.1.2: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.6.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated tailwind-react-native-classnames@1.5.1: library changed name to 'twrnc', please use that package for the latest features
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.      
npm WARN deprecated uglify-es@3.3.9: support for ECMAScript is superseded by `uglify-js` as of v3.13.0

added 1285 packages, and audited 1286 packages in 32s

9 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 6 high, 2 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues, run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I also downloaded Git Bash. I'm open to using any program. Honestly a complete noob and need step by step instructions =D. My main goal is to just open the app and be able to navigate the application.

Answer (score 0):

Install `npm i twrnc` instead of `npm i tailwind-react-native-classnames`